# Some questions about line-height

Tags: css, xhtml

what is default `line-height` of browsers like `font-size` is `16px`?

for which HTML elements i should define `line-height` and for which not?

What is the reason behind to give line-height to `body { }` ?

Will `line-height` effect to single line text?

If I'm using font in `em` then should i also use use `line-height` in `em`?

What is co-relation between `line-height` and `font-size`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, a common default line-height seems to be close to 1.2 (that would be ~19px leading for a 16px font (16*1.2)). In some browsers versions it's about 1.1 - but I can't remember ever seeing it outside that scope.

The line-height property is inherited from parent to child - so specifying a line-height on `<body>` will affect all elements on the page, *except* the ones that have their own line-height property set, and their descendants. (See example below)

Line height affects the height occupied by *each* character - so yes it also has an effect on single-line-of-text elements.

Line-height comes in three basic flavours:

1. 'relative'/'unitless' (e.g. `1.2`)
2. 'fixed' (e.g. `14px`)
3. 'fixed-relative' (e.g. `1.2em`)

Relative (unitless) values will apply proportionally equivalent line-height to all elements depending on their font-size.
Meanwhile, fixed values (`px`) don't change with the font-size.

For explanation of the 'fixed-relative' variant (the 'em'-values) refer to Eric Meyer's blog post "[Unitless Line-Heights](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2006/02/08/unitless-line-heights/)".

Each flavour has it's place in the world. :-)

Here's a short example of all three:

```
body {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
small {
  font-size: 10px;
}
div {
  line-height: 21px;
}
p {
  line-height: 2em;
}

...

<body>
  one
  <small>two</small>
  <div>
    three
    <small>four</small>
  </div>
  <p>
    five
    <small>six</small>
  </p>
</body>
```

Each word in the example above would have the following line-heights (translated into `px`)

- 'one' == 18px  (1.5 times the 12px `font-size` of `body`)
- 'two' == 15px  (1.5 times the 10px `font-size` of `small`)
- 'three' == 21px (fixed `px` value)
- 'four' == 21px (inherits a fixed `px` value from `div`)
- 'five' == 24px (2 times the 12px  `font-size` of `p` (inherited from `body`))
- 'six' == 24px (inherits a (fixed) pre-calculated value from `p`)

Comment: pls reply on my 1st comments under Robert Harvey's answer.

Comment: so, are there any of your questions that are not answered yet?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, the default line height [is about 1.1em](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/css/fonts) (which is relative to the font size being used by the element.

You should set a default line-height in your CSS, and then only modify the line-height in your page when it needs to differ from this.

When you have a requirement that text in the  tag have a specified line-height

Don't understand this question

Only if you need to.

If you are using em's to specify line height, the height will be proportional relative to the font size.

Comment: if i set body `{line-height:1.5}` in body and `p { line-height:2em}` them what would be the line height of `p` ?

Comment: Robert, I see your avatar is "beauty" ... mine is "dream" ... 面白い、ね？

Comment: @metal-gear-solid: it'd be 2em; you can use percent to make it relative to the parent element's line-height - see http://www.htmldog.com/reference/cssproperties/line-height/ . @others: silly people, あたまに風. :)

Answer (score 0):

Line-height is, quite simply, the height of a line of text, but it also applies to elements whose display style is `inline`.

It is equivalent to leading in print typography. Typically, you want a little space between lines of text, and often you will see sites applying an overall line-height of 1.4 or 1.2. A value of 1.4 means they want the line height to be 140% of the text height. If the line-height is set to (or left at) 1, then weird things can happen. When you see an italic word displacing an entire line (making it look uneven) that's what's happened.